# solve $-u''(x)+\int_0^{\pi}u(y)dy=\lambda u(x)$,where $u(0)=u(\pi)=0$

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the eigenvalue problem
$$-u''(x)+\int_0^{\pi}u(y)dy=\lambda u(x)$$for all $ 0\le x\le\pi$, $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ and with $u(0)=u(\pi)=0$.

How to find all the solutions $u$ (in $H^1(0,\pi)$ I think) of this eigenvalue problem?
My first try was to consider $u(x)=a \sin(kx)+b \cos(kx)$ and find out conditions on $a,b,k\in \mathbb{R}$. But I'm not sure if I receive all solutions with this method. Do you know how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a solution $u$, then differentiate:
$$
              -u'''-\lambda u'=0.
$$
Ignoring the case where $\lambda=0$ for the moment,
$$
          u(x)= C+D\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x)+E\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x).
$$
Assuming $u(0)=0$, $u'(0)=1$,
$$
            C+D=0,\;\;\; E\sqrt{\lambda}=1.
$$
The trial solution becomes
$$
              u(x)=C(1-\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x))+\frac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)}{\sqrt{\lambda}}.
$$
Then
$$
          \int_{0}^{\pi}u(t)dt = C\left(\pi-\frac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\right) +\frac{1-\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)}{\lambda}
$$
Plugging into the original equation
$$
    -C\lambda\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x)+\sqrt{\lambda}\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)
   +C\left(\pi-\frac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\right) +\frac{1-\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)}{\lambda} \\
    =C\lambda(1-\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x))+\sqrt{\lambda}\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x),
$$
the constant $C$ is determined by
$$
    C\left(\pi-\frac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)}{\sqrt{\lambda}}-\lambda\right)
    +\frac{1-\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)}{\lambda}=0 \\
     C = - \frac{1-\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)}{\pi\lambda-\sqrt{\lambda}\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)-\lambda^2}
$$
The eigenvalue equation for $\lambda$ is determined by $u(1)=0$, which is an equation in $\lambda$ that can only have real solutions:
$$
       C(1-\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi))+\frac{\sin{\sqrt{\lambda}}\pi}{\sqrt{\lambda}}=0.
$$
Once an eigenvalue $\lambda$ is found, the corresponding solution $u_{\lambda}$ is unique up to a multiplicative constant:
$$
     u_{\lambda}(x) = C(1-\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x))+\frac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)}{\sqrt{\lambda}}.
$$

Comment: I fail to see why you introduced the initial condition $u'(0)=1$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami : Normalization. Any eigenfunction solution is a constant multiple of this one. In general, however, you eliminate all special cases (e.g., $\lambda=0$) by using set values for the function and derivative because the existence/uniqueness theorems for ODES then guarantee you local power series expansions for such $u$ in the variable $\lambda$. Those are two good reasons to normalize in such problems.

Comment: good to know! I had the same question, thanks for your explanation! Thanks for your answer. I can learn a lot from this!!

Comment: @dgl : What has always amazed me when using such normalization for regular problems on a finite interval is how all of the expressions work out to be entire functions of $\lambda$. For example $\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)/\sqrt{\lambda}$, $\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x)$ are entire functions of $\lambda$. The limit of $\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)/\sqrt{\lambda}$ gives the correct case at $\lambda=0$ of $x$.The expression for $C$ is entire. The eigenvalue equation gives solutions that are zeros of an entire function, which means, for example, that the set of eigenvalues cannot have a finite accumulation point.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try fixing $\int_0^\pi u(y)dy=C$ for a constant $C$, and solving this problem as $C$ varies.

Comment: So $C$ is a fixed constant, but it varies?

Comment: Sort of. By setting up the problem this way, we can find all the solutions for which $\int_0^{\pi} u(y)dy=C$. Then, by solving this for all $C$, we must have found all possible solutions.

Comment: πr8 had given the method of solving : With $\:C\:$ unknown,  first solve $\:-u''+C=\lambda u\:$. The result is a function $\:y(x)\:$ containing $\:C\:$ and two arbitrary constants. Then integrate $\:y(x)\:$ from $\:0\:$ to $\:\pi\:$. So, now $\:C\;$ is known.